# Is `:type` part of the Haskell language or command of GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is `:type` part of the Haskell language or a command of GHC?

Does the prefix `:` represent something not part of the language, but of GHC?

Thanks.

Comment: they're just GHCi commands, nothing to do with the Haskell language itself

Comment: No, you can not use `:type` in a program. It is not part of the language itself.

Comment: @RobinZigmond please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: apologies @leftaroundabout - it didn't seem appropriate to post this as an answer, since it's just a few words, and although it certainly answers *a* question, it wasn't clear to me that this would be enough to satisfy the OP

Comment: @RobinZigmond no need to apologise. Just, what you wrote _answers the question as it stands_. It doesn't matter if the answer is only a few words if it is good and complete. If the OP isn't satisfied by this, then he should have phrased the question better (but IMO it's pretty clear, albeit a bit shallow).

Comment: try entering `:help` at GHCi prompt. there's also GHCi documentation somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Commands like `:type`, `:info`, `:load` and so on are just GHCi commands - they're aids to working with Haskell code in an interactive REPL. They have nothing to do with the Haskell language itself.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the GHCI commands are not syntactically valid Haskell tokens. `:`-prefixed identifiers are reserved for symbolic data constructors, which cannot contain alphanumeric characters.